# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document

Tags: soap

i'm trying to use magento soapV2 to create product, here is the script:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<?php


// Magento login information 
$mage_url = 'http://localhost/first/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1'; 

$mage_user = 'rayapi'; 
$mage_api_key = 'Abcd1234'; 
// Initialize the SOAP client 
$client = new SoapClient( $mage_url ); 

$session = $client->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );


$catalogProductCreateEntity = new stdClass();
$additionalAttrs = array();

$catalogProductCreateEntity->name = "product name";
$catalogProductCreateEntity->description = "description";
$catalogProductCreateEntity->short_description = "desc";
$catalogProductCreateEntity->status = "1";
$catalogProductCreateEntity->price = "99";
$catalogProductCreateEntity->tax_class_id = "2";
$catalogProductCreateEntity->websites = array(1,2);
$catalogProductCreateEntity->categories = array(7,15);
$catalogProductCreateEntity->status = 1;
$catalogProductCreateEntity->price = 45;
$catalogProductCreateEntity->tax_class_id = 2;
$catalogProductCreateEntity->weight = 1;

// send the request
$product = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, "simple", 9, 'test_sku', $catalogProductCreateEntity);

// end session and enjoy your updated products :)
$client->endSession($session);

var_dump($product);


?>
```

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\soap.php:71 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\first\soap.php(71): SoapClient->__call('catalogProductC...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\first\soap.php(71): SoapClient->catalogProductCreate('7ab47f189292d99...', 'simple', 9, 'test_sku', Object(stdClass)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\first\soap.php on line 71
```

i tried use 
$result = $client->catalogInventoryStockItemList($session, array('693')); // //Products ID
print_r($result);

catalogInventoryStockItemList is work for me but catalogProductCreate not work.

i googled around but their solution not useful to me, how to solve this problem?

Comment: i just fund another module is blocking the soap create product.

Comment: if your php version 5.6, you can get some errors in SOAP. Using different version may help you.

Comment: @hkguile May i know how you solved the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The SoapFault *looks like we got no XML document* means that the server response is invalid: whitespace before the XML declaration, debug output, no XML at all, whatever…

The server response can be examined via `__getLastResponse()` call.

Adapted to the OPs code example:

```
$client = new SoapClient($mage_url, array('trace' => true));

// […]

try {
    $product = $client->catalogProductCreate($session, "simple", 9, 'test_sku', $catalogProductCreateEntity);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    print($client->__getLastResponse());
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer, but i'm already found the problem. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68363/my-custom-module-is-blocking-the-soap-catalogproductcreate

Comment: seen that, just for reference though.

Comment: @hkguile May i know the solution, above link not working.